how to call matlab from python where the input is list
I want to call a MATLAB function in Python, but it keeps saying "wrong type"
My Python code is as follows:
# Start MATLAB engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

# Add the directory containing your MATLAB function to the MATLAB engine's path
eng.addpath(r"test_function_2D_matlab")  # In the actual code, this path is identical to the one returned by the 'which test_function_2D_matlab' command.

# Define the matrix in Python syntax
X_test = [
    [4.1656, 2.1549],
    [-1.5055, 6.4490],
    [4.9775, 9.5070],
    [9.0715, 13.6937],
    [0.2693, 12.0323],
    [7.1969, 4.0961],
    [2.2232, 7.7268],
    [-3.2281, 0.0208]
]
    
# Convert the Python list to a MATLAB compatible double matrix
X_matlab = matlab.double(X_test)

# Call the MATLAB function and store the result
Y = eng.test_function_2D_matlab(X_matlab)

# Print the result
print(Y)

# Close the MATLAB engine
eng.quit()

And the matlab code is below:
function Y = test_function_2D_matlab(X)
    % Computes the Branin-Hoo test function

    % Constants
    pi_val = pi;
    a = 1;
    b = 5.1 / (2*pi_val)^2;
    c = 5 / pi_val;
    r = 6;
    s = 10;
    t = 1 / (8*pi_val);
    
    % Make sure X is in the correct format
    if size(X, 2) == 1
        X = X'; % Transpose X if it is a column vector
    end
    
    % Compute the Branin-Hoo function
    Y = a * (X(:,2) - b * (X(:,1).^2) + c * X(:,1) - r).^2 + s * (1 - t) * cos(X(:,1)) + s;
end

And when I run it, I will have the error like this:
{
    "name": "MatlabExecutionError",
    "message": "Undefined function 'test_function_2D_matlab' for input arguments of type 'double'.
",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MatlabExecutionError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 24
     21     return Y
     23 X = X_init
---> 24 Y = matlab_2d(X)

Cell In[20], line 17, in matlab_2d(X)
     14 X_matlab = matlab.double(X.tolist())
     15 print(X_matlab)
---> 17 Y = eng.test_function_2D_matlab(X_matlab)
     19 eng.quit()
     21 return Y

File c:\\Users\
12046299\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\envs\\uqlab\\lib\\site-packages\\matlab\\engine\\matlabengine.py:71, in MatlabFunc.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     68     return FutureResult(self._engine(), future, nargs, _stdout, _stderr, feval=True)
     69 else:
     70     return FutureResult(self._engine(), future, nargs, _stdout,
---> 71                         _stderr, feval=True).result()

File c:\\Users\
12046299\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\envs\\uqlab\\lib\\site-packages\\matlab\\engine\\futureresult.py:67, in FutureResult.result(self, timeout)
     64     if timeout < 0:
     65         raise TypeError(pythonengine.getMessage('TimeoutCannotBeNegative'))
---> 67 return self.__future.result(timeout)

File c:\\Users\
12046299\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\envs\\uqlab\\lib\\site-packages\\matlab\\engine\\fevalfuture.py:82, in FevalFuture.result(self, timeout)
     79 if not result_ready:
     80     raise TimeoutError(pythonengine.getMessage('MatlabFunctionTimeout'))
---> 82 self._result = pythonengine.getFEvalResult(self._future,self._nargout, None, out=self._out, err=self._err)
     83 self._retrieved = True
     84 return self._result

MatlabExecutionError: Undefined function 'test_function_2D_matlab' for input arguments of type 'double'.
"
}

Looking forward to your solutions.
I try to convert all the elements one by one to matlab.doule, but it did not work.

Use which test_function_2D_matlab command in matlab to see if your file is properly set. This will return the path of the function. If it returns null, then the path is not even set properly the function is not in the specified folder. You might need to ensure the function format is accurate as well.

You are not showing us the “wrong type” error message. What you post shows “MatlabExecutionError: Undefined function 'test_function_2D_matlab' for input arguments of type 'double'.” This means MATLAB cannot find your function. How did you save it? Where did you save it?

You edited your post, but didn’t  answer my questions, so I still don’t know what you’re doing. Your function test_function_2D_matlab should be saved in a file called “test_function_2D_matlab.m”, and the directory that contains this file should be added to the path (not the file itself).

I'm sorry, Cris. I didn't know how to reply comments. Thanks for your reply! I found why my code was wrong. I included the file name in the path.  Thanks again for your help!
Also thanks the comments from burcu!
